# PowerShell: how to pass argument to exe to run a specific function of the exe?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a function within an EXE that I want to run in PowerShell.

An example of how I am trying to do this :

```
"C:\folder\app.exe 1"
```

Comment: Try calling it from PoSh
`& "C:\folder\app.exe 1"`

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'run a function within an EXE'? Are you saying there is a function compiled into the executable that you want to run?

Answer (score 1):

`start-process "C:\folder\app.exe" -ArgumentList "1"`

Should work, I tested it with notepad and opening a file, worked fine there.

Answer (score 0):

Next time you should research your question as it has been answered dozens of times.

There are many variants to execute an executable from PowerShell, but the one which is least prone to error the following way with the ampersand. As mentioned by Vivek Kumar.

```
$exe = "C:\folder\app.exe"
&$exe 1
```

You can find a detailed explanation in this article:
http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/

Cheers
Glenn